# Django: Display template paths as overlay

Tags: django, templates

I know that django-debug-toolbar has a Templates view that will list all templates invoked on a page request. That's helpful, but I'm looking for something that will go farther and visually show a label on each block of a page, specifying what template was used to draw that block (sort of similar to HTML debug tools like Web Developer's Extension or Firebug).

Is there a package out there that does this already? If not, is there a way for a template to display its own name? With that, I could probably write a custom template tag that would do this in debug mode.

---

**Update:** The final solution we used was a modification of Stephan's solution below. I've packaged up the working versions as a custom template loader in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/shacker/9261885

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you could probably write your own Template class.

```
from django.template.base import Template

class DebugTemplate(Template):
  def _render(self, context):
    rendered_template = Template._render(self, context)
    if settings.DEBUG:
      overlay = Template("overlay.html")
      context = Context({"rendered_template": rendered_template})
      return overlay.render(context)
    return rendered_template
```

Your overlay template would put whatever surrounding html you would want, and use the {{rendered_template}} variable tag to put in the actual contents.

You would then have to make your own loader, to use this Template class instead of the built in Django one. I don't believe there is a setting to specify what Template class to use, but you can specify loaders.

In django/template/loader.py you can find the BaseLoader, and in django/template/loaders/ you can find the loaders themselves. You could create a DebugLoader:

```
from django.template.loader import BaseLoader

class DebugLoader(BaseLoader):
  is_usable = True

  def __init__(self, loaders):
    self._loaders = loaders
    self._cached_loaders = []

  @property
  def loaders(self):
    # Resolve loaders on demand to avoid circular imports
    if not self._cached_loaders:
        # Set self._cached_loaders atomically. Otherwise, another thread
        # could see an incomplete list. See #17303.
        cached_loaders = []
        for loader in self._loaders:
            cached_loaders.append(find_template_loader(loader))
        self._cached_loaders = cached_loaders
    return self._cached_loaders

  def load_template(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
    source = None

    for loader in self.loaders:
      try:
        source, display_name = loader.load_template_source(template_name, template_dirs)
      except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        pass
      else:
        break

    if not source:
      raise TemplateDoesNotExist

    origin = make_origin(display_name, loader.load_template_source, template_name, template_dirs)

    try:
      self.get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
      return template, None
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
      return source, display_name

  def get_template_from_string(self, source, origin, template_name):
    return DebugTemplate(source, origin, name)
```

So, I took parts of that from the CachedLoader, and I didn't put in all the imports. List it in the loaders setting the same as you would the CachedLoader (not sure how it would work with the cached loader itself).

It should get the templates the way each of the other loaders would, then use the DebugTemplate instead of the default Template.

Like I said, I did not test this. This is just what I could come up with, without putting too much effort into it. Let me know any clarification you might need.

Comment: This is more complex than what I was hoping for, but is a brilliant response. Thanks much. I'll edit the question to show the final solution when I get it all wired up. Appreciated!

Comment: OK! I've got this working. I simplified a bit, removing the need for a separate model and template - just the loader, m'aam. Thanks a ton! I've packaged it up in a public gist: https://gist.github.com/shacker/9261885

Answer (score 1):

**A simpler way:**

```
#project/shortcuts.py
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.base import Template,Context
from django.conf import settings

def render_template(request, template, data=None):
    "Wrapper around render_to_response that fills in template name for you"
    if settings.DEBUG:
        temp = Template("template_debug.html")
        context = Context({"rendered_template": template})
        data['template_debug'] = temp.render(context)
    response = render_to_response(template,
        data,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return response

#templates/template_debug.html
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; background-color:#000; color:#fff">
{{ rendered_template }}
</div>
```

Now you have to do two things:
1) Use render_template instead of render_to_response - **added advantage of getting request context.** 
2) put {{ template_debug }} in any template that you want to see where it is getting rendered.

Comment: Not using render_to_response won't be an option in our case (our codebase uses several layers of abstraction that will make this impossible. But I like the approach overall and will be using part of it. I'll edit the question when done to show the final solution. Thanks!